# Give an alias to an object's member

Tags: c++, alias

In C++, is it possible to assign an alias (different name) to an object's members?

As an example, let's say I have a `vec4` with members `x`, `y`, `z`, and `w` that I want to refer to as `r`, `g`, `b`, and `a` respectively.  Is there any way to do this without modifying the definition of `vec4`?

Comment: In short: No, that's not possible. What's the actual problem you want to solve?

Comment: So you want `vec4_object.x` to be the same as `vec4_object.r`?

Comment: @NathanOliver - yeah.  It's likely not possible, but I wanted to double check

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - there's no real problem, I was just curious if this could be done so I could refer to a vec3's contents by different axis, without needing to write a new class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You wont be able to have `vec4_object.r` in place of `vec4_object.x` without modifying `vec4`.

If you can use C++17 then one thing you could do though is use a [structured binding](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding) like

```
vec4 pic = ...;
auto& [pic_r, pic_g, pic_b, pic_a] = pic;
```

and then you can use `pic_r`, `pic_g`, `pic_b` and `pic_a` in place of `pic.x`, `pic.y`, `pic.z` and  `pic.w`

If your `vec4` looks like

```
struct vec4
{
    int x, y, z, w;
};
```

then this works out of the box.  If not you can still provide support to allow this.  You can see how that is done in [this blog post](https://blog.tartanllama.xyz/structured-bindings/)

Comment: @andreee It will, but it requires some plumbing.  That is detailed in the blog post.  Basicaly you have to provide a specialization of `std::tuple_size` for the type and an overload for `get` that returns a reference to each member of the class.

Answer (score 2):

You can't make `v.r` be the same thing as `v.x` unless you either modify the class definition or write `#define r x`, which would obviously cause lots of problems. The closest thing you can do is something like this:

```
constexpr auto r = &vec4::x;
v.*r;  // equivalent to v.x
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
struct base {
    int a;
};

template<typename derived>
struct MemberIntRef {
    struct _ {
        operator int&() {
            auto p = reinterpret_cast<MemberIntRef*>(this);
            auto pd = static_cast<derived*>(p);
            return pd->a;
        }
        
        int& operator=(int a) {
            return operator int&() = a;
        }
    };
    [[no_unique_address]] _ b;
};

struct derived : public MemberIntRef<derived>, public base {
};

int main() {
    derived d;
    d.b = 1;
    std::cout << d.a << std::endl;
    d.a = 2;
    std::cout << d.b << std::endl;
}
```

You can write code in this way. (But I'm not sure whether it is undefined behavior, anybody can help?)https://godbolt.org/z/dc9n7Yfeh